# Is there a way to set custom attributes for component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to set a custom attribute for all elements.

My question is if it is a common html tag, it will run good. e.g: `<div data-class="custom" />`, but if it is a custom component e.g`<Component data-class="custom" />` it will not render `data-class` in html while the `<Component>` does not receive `data-class` from `props`.

Is there a way to set an attribute for `<Component>` without refactor `<Component>`?

Comment: Not directly as far as I know since the component may render whatever it wants (or nothing), but I would think you could make a component that takes whatever is inside it and adds an attribute to the outermost tag

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen ahhh. I just want to set a mark for elements if it has onClick event, if I move these elements to another component it will hard to do with regular expression so I need to write a complex program to do it = =.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this but not sure if it will work or not

```js
let myAttr = {'data-attr': 'value'}

<MyComponent {...myAttr} />
```